# Mongoose: Array of dbref with additional property

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm using mongoose and have two schemas, a `user` and a `album`

```
UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema

  name:                         
    type:     String
    required: true

  albums: [
    type:   mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
    ref:    'Album'
  ]

, collection : 'gallery'

UserModel = mongoose.model 'User', UserSchema


AlbumSchema = new mongoose.Schema

  name:                         
    type:     String
    required: true
    unique:   true

  owner:
    type:   mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
    ref:    'User'

  # ....

, collection : 'gallery'

AlbumModel = mongoose.model 'Album', AlbumSchema
```

Of course AlbumModel has some other properties like `created_time` or `modified_time` and of course `images`. 
Every user is the owner of one or more albums. For performance reasons I want to store a reference of all albums on the user model (is this a `dbref`?). In additionn to the ObjectId I want to store the album name which is the most frequently used property to read next to the id. The result should look something like (as e.g. json):

```
{
    "name":   "John Doe",
    "albums": [
       {
          "id":   "1234567890",
          "name": "Sample album"
       },
       {
          "id":   "9876543210",
          "name": "Sample album 2"
       }
    ]
}
```

Is this possible using mongoose? Is the album name in the user model autoupdated if it's changed (which should happen very rarely)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For performance reasons I want to store a reference of all albums on the user model (is this a dbref?

Yes, a DbRef is just a property in a document that is the ObjectId of a different document.

> Is this possible using mongoose?

Yes, you can define this schema like this:

```
UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema

  name:                         
    type:     String
    required: true

  albums: [{
    id: {
      type:   mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
      ref:    'Album' },
    name: String
  ]
```

> Is the album name in the user model autoupdated if it's changed (which should happen very rarely)?

Nope, but you can use a mongoose postSave hook on the Album schema to keep this denormalized data in sync.

Comment: Using a hook is a good idea. Thank you! Do you recommend to use https://github.com/goulash1971/mongoose-dbref?